# Do Macintosh computers use the same key codes as Windows?

Tags: javascript, windows, keyboard

I've written a game in Javascript on a Windows computer. I'm using onkeydown and onkeyup events to read key presses. My question is, do Macintosh computers use the same keyCodes as Windows? As I don't own a Mac I can't test if all the keys work the same way.

Comment: `keyCode` is not OS-dependent, it's keyboard-dependent. It's better to re-write the code using [keyCode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode), as it's deprecated, and new, more compatible properties are available.

Comment: To clarify what @Teemu said, you should use [`event.key`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key) instead of `event.keyCode`. The page linked here has a list of all the keycodes including OS-specific information where applicable.

Comment: That works great and is clearer than using ascii codes. Is .shiftKey and .ctrlKey okay to use, or is it better to use .key == 'Control' and .key == 'Shift'?

Comment: @Newcolator FYI `event.keyCode` is not ASCII code, it's just a key identifier for the keyboard. Notice ex. a different key code for the same numbers when striked on the top row of the keyboard and on number block.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: Yes.

See https://www.w3.org/TR/uievents-code/ for a full list and comprehensive description.